# How to disable *all* popups in monaco editor for React?

Tags: monaco-editor

If I press enter (or any key actually) in a `readOnly` editor, it shows this:

[image]

I thought I disabled all forms of popups with these `options`:

```
<Editor
  options={{
    acceptSuggestionOnEnter: 'off',
    autoClosingBrackets: 'always',
    contextmenu: false,
    cursorStyle: 'line',
    fontSize: 16,
    hover: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    minimap: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    parameterHints: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    quickSuggestions: {
      comments: false,
      other: false,
      strings: false,
    },
    readOnly,
    scrollbar: {
      alwaysConsumeMouseWheel: false,
      // handleMouseWheel: false,
    },
    suggestOnTriggerCharacters: false,
    tabCompletion: 'off',
    tabSize: 2,
    wordBasedSuggestions: false,
    wordWrap: 'off',
    ...(lineNumbers
      ? {}
      : {
          folding: false,
          glyphMargin: false,
          lineDecorationsWidth: 0,
          lineNumbers: 'off',
          lineNumbersMinChars: 0,
        }),
  }}
/>
```

What am I missing? How do I make sure that absolutely every possible popup is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

try to set both to disable this tooltip:

```
    domReadOnly: true,
    readOnly: true,
```